# How make post in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How make for return post in my method authenticates.?
I like to post to authenticate (method default in spring mvc for authenticate) and before add validate if user is active.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView authenticates(
        @RequestParam("username") String login,
        @RequestParam("password") String password,
        @RequestParam("_spring_security_remember_me") String remember,
        @RequestParam("_csrf") String csrf,
        RedirectAttributes ra
        ) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    Account account = accountService.findByLogin(login);


    if (!account.isActive()) {  
        MessageHelper.addErrorAttribute(ra, "signin.errorUserDown", login, login);
        model.setViewName("redirect:/signin");
        return model;
        //return "redirect:/signin";
    }


    //userService.loadUserByUsername(login);
    //userService.signin(account);


    //model.addObject("submit");
    model.addObject("username", login);
    model.addObject("password", password);
    model.addObject("_spring_security_remember_me", remember);
    model.addObject("_csrf", csrf);
    model.setViewName("signin/signinValidate");

    return model;
    //return "authenticate";
}
```

Comment: What do you expect when user login successfully ? Can you tell me the behavior ?

Comment: When user succesful redirect to page consulted.

Comment: I also had userDetail.setEnable=account.isActive(), but when i consulted SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION in html, this in null, ¿Why?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed of other way.

in html:

```
<span th:text="${session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION'].message}"></span>
```

in userDetails:

```
private User createUser(Account account) {
    boolean enabled = account.isActive();
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    return new User
      (account.getLogin(), account.getPassword(), enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, 
        accountNonLocked, Collections.singleton(createAuthority(account))); 
}
```

finally, personality message with i18n:

```
    <!--/* Show general error message when form contains errors */-->
    <th:block th:if="${param.error != null}">
        <th:block th:if="${session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION'].message.contains('Bad credentials')}">
            <div th:replace="fragments/alert :: alert (type='danger', message=#{signin.errorBadCredentials})">Alert</div>
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION'].message.contains('User is disabled')}">
            <div th:replace="fragments/alert :: alert (type='danger', message=#{signin.errorUserDisabled})">Alert</div>
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION'].message.contains('User account is locked')}">
            <div th:replace="fragments/alert :: alert (type='danger', message=#{signin.errorUserLocked})">Alert</div>
        </th:block>
    </th:block>
```